# How to remove "non-closing" edges in CGAL

Tags: graph, cgal, topology

I have a CGAL Arrangement graph looking like this:

```
,_____,  ,_____,   ,_____,
|     |  |     |   |     |
|--   |  |     |---|     |   ---
|_____|  |_____|   |_____|
```

I want to remove all the edges that doesn't "close" a polygon like the horizontal one inside the square, the one linking the two other squares, and the alone edge.

Is there a way to do this in CGAL? Also, does this kind of edge have a name in topology or in graph theory?

Comment: In graph theory: (1) The edge, connecting two vertices with degree 1, is called "isolated edge". (2) The edge, connecting two vertices, where exactly one of them has degree 1, is called "spike".

Comment: Look for edges that are incident to a single face, in other words, the two opposite halfedges are incident to the same face.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @EfiFogel answer and @HEKTO's highlight of `HalfEdge::face()`, I coded this algorithm that remove every edge that have the same face on its two sides. I don't know if it's possible to improve the complexity, but it works fine with my small amount of edges.

Here it is in C++.

```cpp
template <typename Arrangement>
void removeNonClosingEdges(Arrangement &arrangement)
{
    using Halfedge_handle = typename Arrangement::Halfedge_handle;
    std::vector<Halfedge_handle> uselessEdges;

    for (auto edgeIt = arrangement.edges_begin(), edgeEnd = arrangement.edges_end();
         edgeIt != edgeEnd;
         ++edgeIt)
    {
        Halfedge_handle he = edgeIt;
        if (he->face() == he->twin()->face())
            uselessEdges.push_back(he);
    }

    for (Halfedge_handle uselessHalfEdge : uselessEdges)
        arrangement.remove_edge(uselessHalfEdge, false, false);

    // Remove all isolated vertices
    typename Arrangement::Vertex_iterator iter = arrangement.vertices_begin();
    while (iter != arrangement.vertices_end())
    {
        // Keep an iterator to the next vertex, as curr might be deleted.
        typename Arrangement::Vertex_iterator curr = iter++;
        if (curr->is_isolated())
            arrangement.remove_isolated_vertex(curr);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Use simpler approach thanks to @EfiFogel and @HEKTO

Comment: Why not to use the suggested by @EfiFogel approach? I mean the condition: `he.face() == he.twin().face()`

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about the face() method. I edited the answer accordingly.